# How can I get the printfs coming from c functions displayed in the console with node-ffi

Tags: javascript, node.js, c, node-ffi

I am loading in javascript using node-ffi a C DLL , I was obliged to comment all the printfs coming from the DLL to not crash the application
Is there any solution to get those printfs displayed in the console of nodejs using node-ffi ?

Comment: Redirect stdout to wherever you want the output to go?

Comment: I don't want to modif my C DLL , all the developement will be in javascript , node-ffi will be the interface ,I want that the printfs coming from the call of c functions in nodejs will be displayed in the nodejs environment

Comment: That's the whole point of redirecting stdout: to avoid modifying the DLL.

Comment: Actually That is exactly What I don't want to do because this DLL is used as input for several other application in C++ and java , what I would like to do is to keep the DLL as it is without modifying the printfs and got the results displayed in node

Comment: The only reasonably good way to capture the output from the printf statements is to redirect stdout.

Comment: Already followed that solution ,thanks Robert